# Bootstrap Tooltip not working for dynamically generated rows

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table in which rows are generated dynamically. I have to add `tooltip` to one of the cells in all the dynamically generated rows. The `tooltip` is working for `<th></th>` but not for the `<td></td>`

Here is my table

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th id="table-head" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="" data-content="Sample Tootlip">Table Head</th></tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in Samplelist">
<td class="tableContent" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="" data-content="Content Tootlip">{{item.value}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And Here is the JQuery

```
$('.tableContent').popover({
                container: 'body',
                placement: 'left',
                trigger: 'hover'

            });
$('#table-head').popover({
                container: 'body',
                placement: 'left',
                trigger: 'hover'

            });
```

The tooltip is appearing in `<th></th>` but not in `<td></td>`
Is it because its dynamic how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption that the problem is because the rows are being created dynamically. So the DOM elements don't exist when the

```
.popover({...})
```

function is called.

### Solution:

What you need to do is call the,

```
.popover()
```

function when you hover over your element.

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.tableContent', function () {
    if ($(this).attr('data-toggle') != 'popover')
    {
        $(this).popover({
            container: 'body',
            placement: 'left',
            trigger: 'hover'
        }).popover('show');
    }
});
```

## Explanation

When the mouse hovers over your element a check is done whether the **data-toggle** has been added yet, if it has not been added the **.popover()** function is called adding the **data-toggle** and also the ***popover('show')*** is called to actually show the item on the first hover.

After this the popover funtion should work normally on hover.

Hope it helps. Happy Coding.

Comment: if ($(this).attr('data-toggle') == 'popover')    it should be == not !=